# CSP reporting to another origin

Tags: content-security-policy

I was implementing a CSP policy and set up the reporting endpoint as another domain, a completely separate origin. Everything seemed to work fine, but talking to a few friends they seemed surprised that it worked as they thought that CSP reports could only go to the same domain or a subdomain. I looked around online and read through the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/#security-violation-reports) but didn't find anything that substantiated their theory that it used to be that way.

I'm cautious going forward because I'd rather set up a reporting endpoint that I could get consistently rather than one that might fail on older browsers. Is there any truth to their suspicions that cross-origin reporting used to not be supported?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tested this at scale with a wide variety of browsers there does not seem to be any issue with the reporting endpoint being on a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout all versions of CSP ([v1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-CSP1-20150219/), [v2 current](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/2/#directive-report-uri), [v3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/)) there has been no limitation on where the reports can be sent by the browser. The `report-uri` directive expects a URL, the following is taken directly from the spec:

```
The report-uri directive specifies a URL to which the user agent sends reports about policy violation.
```

Historically browsers would not send a CORS pre-flight for the reports, which technically put them in violation of the SOP, but modern versions of Chrome now pre-flight a CSP report. This means you need to answer OPTIONS requests with the appropriate ACAO headers if you want the browser to send reports.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are businesses centered around collecting these reports (e.g. the eponymous `report-uri.com`), it's obvious there are no limitation on the origin.